# Facebook: Who can see what others post on your timeline, and the newsfeeds of restricted lists

Tags: facebook

When a list of friends is restricted from seeing other friends' posts on my wall through the option "Who can see what others post on your timeline?", can the restricted list of friends still see the same posts on their news feed?

I have some family members who are getting irritated by what some of my other friends are posting on my wall. If the restricted list can still see the posts on their newsfeed, then that doesn't really solve anything. Facebook warns you that hidden posts can still be viewed on other people's newsfeeds, but I don't see how that can be the case, or what's even the point of hiding posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visibility of what another person posts is controlled by that other person and you cannot do anything at all.

When you put someone to your restricted list, you are removing posts from them and about them from your view - not your restricted friend's view.

Basically, the problem is that some other people are seeing posts from some other people that they do not wish to see. So, it is those some other people who need to change their settings, you can of do anything from your account.